# Design patterns to ease migration of SQL code between vendors

Tags: sql, database, data-migration

I am looking at ways which a developer can take advantage of implementation specific advanced features(T-SQL, PL-SQL etc) and at the same time makes it easy to migrate the ANSI compliant SQL code to a new database. By that I mean, how to efficiently abstract the ANSI compliant SQL code and move it across different databases?

Comment: Care to explain the down vote?

Comment: It may be too late for this but one approach I've adopted is to always code in ANSI-compliant code in the first instance, then comment out (rather than delete) the code you need to change to get it to work on the given SQL platform.

Comment: The down vote was probably from someone who thinks that aspiring to portable code via ANSI compliance is a waste of time and effort.

Comment: Am I wrong in assuming that each SQL variant is like a different flavor of C (gnu, MS, borland)? If that's the case, each vendor has different set of functions. To counter this, we usually wrap implementation specific functions in our own API and use that. How can we achieve the same in SQL is my question. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [Mimer SQL validators](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml):

> Check Your SQL Against the SQL-92
>   Standard. Mimer SQL-92 Validator
>   recognizes the standards Entry,
>   Transitional, Intermediate and Full
>   SQL-92, Persistent Stored Modules
>   (PSM) SQL-99 and Database Triggers

Copy and paste SQL text into the webpage and hit the 'Test SQL' button.

..though I'm not sure that is the kind of "efficient" process you are looking for, it may of some use.

Comment: Thank you! Like packages and classes in Java/C#, is there a way to logically organize my SQL code?